# TFRecord reading pipeline slows down after PREFETCH samples

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I have divided my training data into multiple tf-record files, and read them using this piece of code:

```
SHUFFLE_BUFFER = 64
PREFETCH = 256
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER) 
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_image_function, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(PREFETCH)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
```

This dataset is fed directly to model.fit(dataset).

The first PREFETCH samples are loaded quickly, and GPU utilization is constantly above 80%. However, after that the fast reading seems to stop, GPU utilization drops, and training time slows down massively. 
Anyone know what might be going wrong?

Comment: [TF 2.2.0 will include a profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras). I suggest you install tf-nightly and use that profiler to see where the bottlenecks are in your code, and then focus on reducing those bottlenecks.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of hard to diagnose without knowing more details (storage backend, record size, number of records per file, number of files, any io operations in _parse_image_function?, ....)

My first suspicion is on tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames) - opening one file after the next may introduce latency spikes that could temporarily starve the dataset cpu pipeline. (Multiple smaller files may also have lower benefits from automatic read aheads)

I would try to add an additional prefetch right after tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames) to decouple IO (and maybe interleave records from different files (num_parallel_reads argument)).

If the prefetch does not help I would try to hard code num_parallel_calls (mostly because I have not read the autotune code yet - and maybe use a private thread pool if your pipeline needs more then the default parallelism).

Depending on your storage backend - repeated training restarts once training slows down (to test/optimize the dataset) may just pull data from various caches and may slow down once the used dataset exceeds the caches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I toyed around with the suggestions you gave, but it keeps being a challenge to figure out the right setting for everything. In the end I used iotop, htop, and nvidia-smi to find possible bottlenecks and used that to optimize the pipeline. 
One additional parameter which your answer does not include which did speed up my data pipeline is enabling compressions of the tf-records :)

Comment: Hi @rmeertens, can you share what parameters helped you improve this issue? I'm facing a similar issue as well. Thanks!